# Phone won't boot after Cyanogenmod 10.2 update

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-one-x

I just updated my HTC One X from Cyanogenmod 10.1.13 to 10.2 RC1, which seemed to go smoothly.

It completed the "Checking apps" stage, and when it rebooted, it got stuck on the boot screen (the spinning concentric circles) for about 15 minutes, at which point I held the power button to turn off the phone, but it just restarted and it's stuck in the same place.

What are my options? The problem I have at the moment is I can't turn on or off the phone (just restart) and I also can't get adb to work when I connect it to my PC.

(oh, and no...I didn't backup before updating - because that would have been a smart thing to do)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could it be that the upgrade from 10.1 to 10.2 also requires a factory reset?

Comment: Nope, according to [here](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-10-2-rc1), "You can safely flash this on top of CM 10.1 (any version) without wiping data IF you also manually update your third party add-on zips (kernels, mods, packs, etc)." Is there something else I need to update?

Comment: As long as you also flashed any new kernels, you it looks like that's not the problem.

Comment: That's what I'm unsure about! All I did was used the built-in updater function in the settings, to download the update and install it automatically. Do I also need to download the new kernel and flash it?

Comment: Perhaps, but I actually don't think so. That said, I'm not particularly familiar with CM practices lately - and I'm even more disconnected with the kernel/ROM scene for HTC phones. I scanned a few XDA threads trying to find information for you, but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Yeah, I've been looking on XDA too but I can't find anything. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem myself in the end.

The solution: I had to flash the boot.img file.
To do this:

- Download the CM update from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/) that matches the update you installed. Make sure you choose the correct device as well. (HTC One X is "Endeavoru")
- Unzip the file, and copy the boot.img file to C:\Android\android-sdk\tools (or wherever you have the Android dev stuff installed).
- Boot your phone into the bootloader (power button + volume down for HTC One X) and choose Fastboot from the menu, using the volume buttons to go up and down the list and the power button to choose.
- Connect your phone to your PC via USB. It will install Fastboot drivers.
- Open a command prompt window and cd to the \tools directory mentioned above. Run the command `fastboot devices` to make sure your phone is connected.
- If it shows, run `fastboot flash boot boot.img` to flash the boot.img file to your phone.
- Finally run `fastboot reboot` to restart the phone. Your phone will go through the "Android is upgrading" process and you should be back in business once that finishes.

You will also need to flash gapps or any other custom mods/addons you had installed before upgrading. There are plenty of guides online explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wipe data/factory reset and wipe cache partition? This worked for me when I flashed the ROM on my Galaxy S3.

Answer (score -1):

a faster way odo it is download the cm rom to yu micro sd card  and istall the update (by the waythis only works if you have a clowckwokod or teamwin recovery ) then install then go to installupdatefromsdcard1>downloads(or whatever folder it may be in)>yes and let it insall, the n re-root the device after update is installed then after root file is complete reboot into recovery and reset device and reboot after that it works

Comment: Can you add some punctuation and capitalization to remove the stream of consciousness aspect to this answer? I'm also not sure about your correct spelling of the products you mention in the (parentheses).